# Можно ли прокинуть сетевой интерфейс микротика в одной сети?

Tags: маршрутизация

Добрый день. Нужно сделать такой костыль. Есть 2 микротика. 
1 выступает в роли DHCP
2 выступает в виде шлюза
К первому подключили ещё один интернет(спутниковый). Я хочу заворачивать весь траффик гугла на этот спутник. Как это реализовать? По идее нужно как то прокинуть интерфейс на 2й микротик и там уже рулить. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно было просто маркировать пакеты с одного интерфейса и заворачивать их в сеть прописав дефолтный маршрут.